# OpenCV Detect "Splotchy" Lines

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am attempting to use OpenCV to detect "splotchy" lines in a binary image. I have an image like the one below and would like to robustly detect the three roughly vertical lines of splotches. `HoughLines` does a decent job, but often fails if only a few of the white pixels in the splotches are perfectly colinear. I've also tried Generalized Hough transform functions, but they aren't much better.

[image: Binary Image]

What I would like to be able to do is have `HoughLines` perform the Hough transform and give me the image in the Hough space (where each pixel value represents the votes for a particular rho and theta). That way I could look for high density regions instead of peaks, as those regions may better represent the lines I'm looking for.

I can't seem to find a way to get the raw Hough space image however. Is it possible?

Are there better ways to detect splotchy lines like this?

As a side note, I would like to do this all on a GPU, so functions with a 'cv::cuda::` api would be best.

Comment: can you please show both the good example and bad example?

Comment: Did you tried [fitLine](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitline#fitline)? I think is the perfect application for Linear Regression.

Comment: @CarlosSanmartínBustos, do you mean treating each white pixel like a point in a scatter plot? That's an interesting approach. I would need to filter out the outliers somehow... I also need to be able to detect multiple lines in a single image, so that might be tricky

Comment: @appleapple, I've updated the post with a new image containing lines that HoughLines struggles to detect without also giving too many false positives.

Comment: are they always vertical? Is it 3 or 4 in your image (1 left, 2 middle (close to each other?), 1 right)?

Comment: @micka, they won't always be vertical. There are only 3 lines in the image. Center-right splotches are noise.

Comment: I think you can just iterate over all the contour center points and put all the x-coordinates in a list, then you can use k-means to get the x-coordinates of these 3 lines.

Comment: if there are multiple lines, will they always be kind of parallel?

Comment: @ZdaR, I like that idea. The only problem is that lines won't always be vertical, so then I'd pretty much be doing a linear fit on a scatter plot, but looking for multiple lines. Are there simple ways to do that?

Comment: @Micka, lines will always be parallel

Comment: can you add a few more sample images?